# Test input with readMaybe

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to develop a calculator for a project in college.
In the project and I can use the internal memory of it to execute operations. That's the problem. I am not able to separate the entries, when it is a String and when it is a Float. If it is a string I need to look for that string in memory, in case it is a float I need to transform from String that it came to Float and then use in the calculation. The solution I found so far was this:

```
   'calculator :: Memory -> IO Memory
   'calculator mem = do
       x <- getLine
       let k = if isNothing (readMaybe (head (tail (words x))))
           then find mem (head (tail (words x)))
           else getVar1 x
           j = if isNothing (readMaybe (head (tail (words (x)))))
           then find mem (head (tail (tail (words x))))
           else getVar2 x'
```

I have a memory which is the type of [Conteudo] and Conteudo is equal to (String,Float).
when using the calculator, for example, you want to add 5 and 9, you type add 5 9
the result is printed on the screen and the value is saved in a position of my Memory as ("ans", 14). You have the possibility to put another command that would be put A. It will store in an A position of Memory the value of ans example :( "A", 14). My problem would be that I can not mix the two inputs. for example add A 8.

it prints this error

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `readMaybe'
  prevents the constraint `(Read a0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Read Lexeme -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
    instance Read Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
    instance Read Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
    ...plus 23 others
    ...plus six instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the first argument of `isNothing', namely
    `(readMaybe (head (tail (tail (words x)))))'
  In the expression:
    isNothing (readMaybe (head (tail (tail (words x)))))
  In the expression:
    if isNothing (readMaybe (head (tail (tail (words x))))) then
        find mem (head (tail (tail (words x))))
    else
        getVar2 x
```

If anyone can help me thank you

Comment: Oof, this question needs work. At very least, please include sample input/output from `'calculator` (it's not clear what it is your function is trying to do). Preferably give an outline of what's using `'calculator` too, because lines like `isNothing (readMaybe (head (tail (words x))))` don't read as very Haskell-y, and can probably be improved elsewhere, too.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. When providing a code example, the example should ideally be complete (i.e. compile as is). That doesn't mean you have to dump all of your code here; It's ok to find a small example that exhibits the same problem you're having.

Also, a problem description should always include the actual problem. "It does not work" does not tell us what does not work.

That being said, this doesn't even compile. `'calculator` is not valid function name in Haskell.

Comment: A general comment: if your code involves `head,tail,isNothing,fromJust` it is likely that you are doing something wrong. You should use pattern matching instead, which is simpler, safer, and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting is because you haven't told GHC what type it's supposed to be reading the string into. Compare with, in GHCI:

```
Prelude> read "3.2"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
Prelude> read "3.2" :: Float
3.2
```

---

However, the better solution would be to make a product type that encompasses both possibilities, and a function that can evaluate either case to a `Num`.

```
data Term = Name  String
          | Value Float

eval :: Memory -> Term -> Float
eval _   (Value n) = n
eval mem (Name  s) = find mem s  -- presumably?
                                 -- though this should probably give a Maybe Float
```

then you can use `readMaybe` to implement a parser.

```
parseTerm :: String -> Term
parseTerm s = case (readMaybe s :: Maybe Float) of
              Just v  -> Value v
              Nothing -> Name  s
```